# Should the mysql system database have its encoding and collation updated?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, utf8mb4

The background:

I have an old MariaDB 5.5 installation which has all configuration defaults, databases, tables and columns set to utf8/utf8_general_ci. I want to change everything to utf8mb4/utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

My question:

Should I also update the "mysql" system table?

Looking at it, that schema appears to be utf8/utf8_general_ci. I don't know if that's because the server was initialised with that as a default configuration, or because that's what it should be. Does it even matter?

The side question:

If I decide to dump all databases in an effort to enable the `files_per_table` option and reimport all the databases, should I include the "mysql" system database in this endeavour?

Comment: I wouldn't mess with the mysql database other than to make sure you run mysql_upgrade.exe. Even at 10.5.5 those are the collations being used for the mysql database.

Comment: And don't reload `mysql` or `performance_schema` or `information_achema`.